# Неизданными или Не изданными?

Tags: частица-не

Неизданными до сегодняшнего дня произведениями являются:
Неизданными или Не изданными?
Заголовок:
Неизданные книги
или  Не изданные книги?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
     Заголовок: Неизданные книги или Не изданные книги?
```

Неизданные - прилагательное в значении "рукописные" - слитное написание.

```
  Неизданными до сегодняшнего дня произведениями являются
  Неизданными или Не изданными?
```

*Не изданными* - причастие (те, которые так и не издали до сегодняшнего дня).

Причастие с **не** пишется раздельно, если есть зависимые слова:   до сегодняшнего дня.

*Не изданными до сегодняшнего дня произведениями являются...*

Было бы слитно: *До сегодняшнего дня являются неизданными произведения..*.

Comment: А если следом идёт раздел с заголовком ИЗДАННЫЕ КНИГИ, не будет ли тогда противопоставления и раздельное написание НЕ ИЗДАННЫЕ КНИГИ?

Comment: Ну и что, что противопоставление? Это же в разных предложениях, тем более в заголовках. Раздельно было бы, если бы противопоставление было с союзом А: не изданные книги, а рукописные. Мало того, если Вы употребите во 2 примере "не изданными" в значении прилагательного "рукописные"  (рукописными до сегодняшнего дня произведениями являются), то в этом случае тоже будет слитное написание, но у Вас такой оговорки нет.

Comment: А вообще таких заголовков("Изданные") лучше не допускать, можно написать: Печатные издания. Рукописные произведения.

Comment: Убедили, спасибо!

Comment: А почему тогда не приняли его?